# dynamically loading and unloading js files

Tags: javascript

Currently I have an website where each page on the site has a corresponding js file that contains a class (well function) defined in it. Currently when the user navigates to another page (which is just ajax content) I remove the old script tag from the page and add a new script tag for the new page. This is working though I was wondering if there could be any problems with this or better ways to do it? I've been thinking of using an AJAX call (XMLHTTPRequest) to get the new js file then using eval to initiate the new page.

Comment: When you say "unloading" what do you mean?  The code has already been executed, so removing the `<script>` would make no difference, right?

Comment: by unloading I'm removing the script tag because the new content displayed on the page no longer needs that .js file. Also all references to the javascript loaded from that .js file are nulled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing makes sense because the browser can intelligently cache the js.

Getting the js yourself might prevent the possibility to cache.